# Cross-compiling V8 for Arm - hello-world hangs during Initialize

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, v8

I'm trying to build and run the hello-world.cc sample from [Getting started with embedding V8](https://v8.dev/docs/embed).  I'm cross-compiling from Linux x86 (Hyper-V Ubuntu Virtual machine on Windows 10 Native OS) to Linux Arm64 (happens to be an NVIDIA Jetson Nano).

When I run the sample, it hangs in the [`v8::V8::Initialize`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc#L18) function.

I'm not sure what went wrong.  But I'll do my best to outline the steps I took.

#### On the x86 build system (Virtual machine).

I checked out out depot_tools according to [these instructions](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up) and did the associated follow up steps (updated with `gclient sync` and `./build/install-build-deps.sh`

I fetched v8 according to [these instructions](https://v8.dev/docs/source-code) and did `glient sync`.

I built ninja from scratch:

```
git clone git://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git && cd ninja
git checkout release
cat README.md
./configure.py --bootstrap
cp ninja /usr/local/bin
```

I installed clang

```
sudo apt-get install clang-7 clang-tools-7 clang-7-doc libclang-common-7-dev libclang-7-dev libclang1-7 clang-format-7 python-clang-7
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s ../lib/llvm-7/bin/clang clang
sudo ln -s ../lib/llvm-7/bin/clang++ clang++
```

I set up gn

```
gn
git clone https://gn.googlesource.com/gn
cd gn
python build/gen.py
ninja -C out
```

Then I tried to build V8:

```
cd ~/v8/v8
/home/username/gn/out/gn gen out.gn/arm64.release
/home/username/gn/out/gn args out.gn/arm64.release
```

I used these gn args:

```
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "arm64"
v8_target_cpu = "arm64"
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
target_os = "linux"
```

Then I copied the out.gn/aarch64.release folder to the target arm machine and tried to compile the sample on that machine.

#### On the Arm64 machine

```
clang++ -I. -Iinclude src/hello-world.cc -o hello_world -lv8_monolith -Lout.gn/arm64.release/obj -pthread -stdlib=libc++ -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS

./hello_world
```

This example hangs in `v8::V8::Initialize`.  I verified this by adding print statements after each line in the hello-world.cc file.

I may have neglected to provide the details in this post regarding installing some build essentials (I have built other things from this VM before, so it's been a while.)  I also neglected to detail how I did basically a symmetric checkout of v8 on the Arm system (I just didn't actually build v8 on that system.)

I am able to build V8 for x86 within the VM and build and run the hello-world embedding sample on that system.  But cross compiling for Arm and trying to build and run the sample on the Arm system, it just hangs during Initialize.

I don't know what I may have done wrong or what to investigate further.

#### Updates

It appears that the stack is beneath:  `v8::internal::ComputeFlagListHash()`

```
#0  0x0000000000408e80 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)@plt ()
#1  0x0000000000469064 in std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) ()
#2  0x0000007fb7f1eb24 in std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1
#3  0x000000000040a6ec in std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) ()
#4  0x000000000040a1d4 in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) ()
#5  0x00000000004c7184 in v8::internal::ComputeFlagListHash() ()
#6  0x00000000005af44c in v8::internal::V8::InitializeOncePerProcessImpl() ()
#7  0x0000000000adf744 in v8::base::CallOnceImpl(std::__1::atomic<unsigned char>*, std::__1::function<void ()>) ()
#8  0x00000000005af318 in v8::internal::V8::Initialize() ()
#9  0x000000000042e5f4 in v8::V8::Initialize(int) ()
#10 0x0000000000409b88 in main ()
```

I'm concerned it may be something to do with float instruction set.

FYI: /proc/cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv8 Processor rev 1 (v8l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x1
CPU part        : 0xd07
CPU revision    : 1
```

(...actual output is repeated times 4 processors)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a small thing.  I was linking against the wrong standard library implementation.  I just had to add this to my gn args:

```
use_custom_libcxx = false
```

And then remove the `-stdlib=libc++` option.  (Should have known, it was suspicious that I had to add it in the first place to get rid of linker errors.)

I must say, it was weird that it just looped forever rather than crashing.